# Unable to connect to SQL Server 19 using PHP and Docker

Tags: php, dockerfile, sqlsrv

This is my PHP code to connect to my database. This code works when running it using XAMPP, I am able to connect to the database and retrieve and insert into a table. I have added this to php.ini extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64.dll

```
function DBConnect(){
  $serverName = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"; //I am able to connect to SQL Server from other computers, I have tried this, instead of 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS' I use tcp:<computername>,<port>
  $connectionInfo = [
    "Database"=>"", //removed DB name for this
    "Uid"=>"",
    "PWD"=>""
  ];

  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
  if(!$conn){
    echo die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return $conn;
  }
}
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.10-apache
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql18 unixodbc-dev 
RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
RUN docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

And this is the error which returns when I run the docker container:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => HYT00
            [SQLSTATE] => HYT00
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => 11001
            [code] => 11001
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => 11001
            [code] => 11001
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
        )

)
```

Comment: How are you starting your container? Are you exposing the correct ports?
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: I am just using port 80. I am very new to this, what ports should I be exposing?